# Найти max сумму элементов пирамиды

Tags: javascript

Есть такая пирамида массивов:

```
[
  [3],
  [7, 4],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [8, 5, 9, 3] 
]
```

Нужно найти максимальную сумму ее элементов сверху вниз. Пример:

```
 /3/
 \7\ 4 
2 \4\ 6 
8 5 \9\ 3
```

Пока не пойму даже, как реализовать. Пока получается сделать сумму столбцов:

```js
function longestSlideDown(pyramid) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < pyramid.length; i++) {
    var subarr = pyramid[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < subarr.length; j++) {
      if (result[j] == undefined)
        result[j] = 0;
      result[j] += subarr[j];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(longestSlideDown([
  [3],
  [7, 4],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [8, 5, 9, 3]
]));
```

Comment: Вам просто нужно вывести максимальное значение из всех массивов?

Comment: мне нужно найти из всех массивов максимальную сумму элементов сверху вниз, как я показал в примере выше...

Comment: Т.е. вывести `3,7,4,9` ?

Comment: вывести их сумму т.е ответ должен быть 23

Comment: А причём тут сверху вниз?

Comment: кажется доперла, можно в цикле перебирать все массивы и находить в них максимальный элемент и просто суммировать их.

Comment: не совсем верно я сказал, тогда ответ получается 25...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52661/discussion-between-lesha310392-and-yuri).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно прибавлять к результату максимальный результат.

```
Массив 1: Макс. = 3  
Массив 2: Макс. = 7  
Массив 3: Макс. = 6  
Массив 4: Макс. = 9
```

Вот рабочий пример:

```js
function longestSlideDown(pyramid) {
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < pyramid.length; i++) {
    var subarr = pyramid[i];
    var max = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < subarr.length; j++) {
      if(max < subarr[j]){
        max = subarr[j];
      };
    };
    result = result + max;
  };
  return result;
};

console.log(longestSlideDown([
  [3],
  [7, 4],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [8, 5, 9, 3]
]));
```

Вот рабочий пример по условию задачи автора вопроса:

```js
function longestSlideDown(pyramid) {
  var result = 0,
      maxElem = null; // Задаём максимальное значение в массиме
  for (var i = 0; i < pyramid.length; i++) {
    var subarr = pyramid[i];
    var max = 0; // Максимальное число
    if(maxElem == null){ 
      // Если индекса максимального значения нет, то считаем по обычному принципе
      var maxVal = pyramid[i].length,
          minVal = 0
    }else{
      // Если значение максимального есть, то ищем элементы с отклонением в один индекс от прошлого максимального
      var maxVal = maxElem + 1,
          minVal = maxElem - 1
    };
    for (var j = minVal; j <= maxVal; j++) {
      if(max < subarr[j]){
        maxElem = j;
        max = subarr[j];
      };
    };
    result = result + max;
  };
  return result;
};

console.log(longestSlideDown([
  [3],
  [7, 4],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [8, 5, 9, 3]
]));
```

Comment: @lesha310392, с чего он должен 23 выводить? Если сложить все максимальные значения будет `25`

Comment: по условиям задачи ответ 23...я вверху привел пример как должны считаться элементы...вот и не могу догнать как так сделать

Comment: @lesha310392, я догнал. Сейчас попробую сделать

Comment: Это какой-то абсурд! Почему на втором с верху сдвиг влево, а на втором справа сдвиг вправо?

Comment: @lesha310392, смотрите пример по вашему вопросу

Answer (score 2):

Использую особенность reduce и преобразования массива с одним элементом.
Если массив с одним элементом преобразовать, то становится строкой.
В итоге получается, что в первую итерацию в last передается строка, которую я преобразую в число и складываю со след. значением из след. по списку массива.

```js
const pyramid = [
  [3],
  [7, 4],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [8, 5, 9, 3] 
];

const a = pyramid.reduce((last, cur, i) => {
 return parseInt(last) + cur[i - 1]
});

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [
  [3],
  [7, 4],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [8, 5, 9, 3] 
];

console.info(arr.reduce((a, _) => a += Math.max(..._), 0));
```